# In c++ using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

How do you display the last character in a character array when you don't know how big the array is?
Would array *('\0' - 1) work?

Comment: No it would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a character array contains a C-style string, ie it contains a null terminator, then you can apply the standard C function `strlen()`, like this:

```
char s[] = "Hello";
//...
size_t n = strlen( s );

if ( n != 0 ) std::cout << s[n-1] << '\n';
```

Otherwise, you can write a template function like this:

```
template <size_t N>
char last_char( const char ( &s )[N] )
{
    return s[N-1];
}
```

and call it like this:

```
char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };

std::cout << last_char( s ) << '\n';
```

Comment: FYI, in C++17 and later, you can use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the size of a fixed array, so you don't need to write a custom template for that: `size_t n = std::size(s); std::cout << s[n-1] << '\n';` If you are not using a C++17 compiler, you can write your own templated `size()` function: `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t size(const T (&s)[N]) { return N; }`